# simpler mdx filter solution

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, mdx

I have a query which returns results for last 12 months, and I need to apply a filter in a way, that only product models with particular measure in last 7 months > 0 (at least in one of these months) are returned.

I could do it in this way:

```
 SELECT {[Measures].[MQ]} ON COLUMNS, 
FILTER([dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].members, (([Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-08-01],[Measures].[MQ]) > 0)   OR (([Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-09-01],[Measures].[MQ]) > 0) OR  ([Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-10-01],[Measures].[MQ]) > 0) * {[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-08-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-02-01]} ON ROWS FROM [cub_dashboard_spares]
```

(I left other ORs conjuctions) So I would need 6 ORs which I dont like,
somehow it is not possible to write the filter it in this way as I would expect (pseudocode):

```
FILTER([dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].members, (ANY({[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-08-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-02-01]}),[Measures].[MQ]) > 0)
```

, is there please some trick/syntax how to avoid using mutliple ORs? Like ANY or idk..

thank you very much for help in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You could use another `Filter()` and check if that has at least one result with `Count`:

```
FILTER([dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].members,
       FILTER({[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-08-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-02-01]}),
              [Measures].[MQ]) > 0
             ).Count > 0
      )
```

Assuming there are no negative values of `MQ`, you can also observe that if at least one month has values > 0, then the sum must be > 0, and use

```
FILTER([dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].members,
       Sum({[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-08-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-02-01]}),
           [Measures].[MQ]
          )
        > 0
      )
```